# Create list of user in C++

Tags: c++, list

I have create a system login with a list but whenever i add new user,the old user will be removed.How can i create a list of user?

void userRegisterDo()
{

```
ofstream usersFile ("userData.txt");

if (    !usersFile.is_open())
{
    usersFile.open("userData.txt");
}

    usersFile << username << " " << password << endl;

    usersFile.close();
    system("cls");
    login();
}

    // Initialize user registration
void userRegister()
{
cout << "Welcome!\n-------------------------\n\nPlease register.\nEnter a new username:\n";
cin >> username;

cout << "\nPlease enter a new password:\n";
cin >> password;

userRegisterDo();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fstream::app` as second parameter while opening the file.

This would open the file in append mode and hence won't overwrite the previous content.

Comment: where do i put the fstream::app?

Comment: like this - `ofstream usersFile ("userData.txt", fstream::app);`

Comment: @user2947488 glad it worked, would you mind accepting my response as answer?